# set focus on a button

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a simple xpage with 2 inputText field (username and password) and a button.

The idea is that when hitting the "return" or "enter" key , that the onclick event of the button will be activated. I guess this is normally done with an auto onfocus, but can't find a way to let this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best is to define a small function from a js library you load in each page you need this

```
function fireButton(e, buttonId) {
    if (typeof e == "undefined" && window.event) {
        e = window.event;
    }

    if (e.keyCode == dojo.keys.ENTER) {
        dojo.byId(buttonId).click();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Then in the `onkeydown` attribute you can call it:

```
<xp:inputText onkeydown="fireButton(event, '#{id:buttonId}')"
```

Comment: I can't get it to work, but that's probably me ...I made a script library (gave it the same name as the function) Then added "import fireButton" at onclientload of the page .Then added "fireButton(event, '#{id:button1}') in the onkeydown of the second inputtext field , but it doesn't work

Comment: How did you declare the library in the page? Have you opened the browser developer console to see where it gets cranky about?

Comment: I get :"Uncaught ReferenceError: fireButton is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeydown" , so it seems the function is not loaded ? How do I do this properly ?

Comment: Sorry , my mistake. I saved it as a serverside javascript library instead of client side. It works perfect now ! (I also changed the name so that the name of the library and function are not the same )

Answer (score 0):

From the Button's "All Properties" tab, set `type` to `submit`,

[image: as shown in this screenshot.]

Comment: Setting the `type` on the first properties tab doesn't seem to work properly, as it affects the properties of the event handler (onclick) attached to the Button, not the Button itself... weird.